# Return and Store string from an execute statement to be used later

Tags: sql-server, variables, concatenation, string-concatenation, varchar

I've got a procedure call that is used by several groups/processes etc.

The call works as follows:

```
EXEC LWP_PAYMENT_URL @order_no, @dept
```

and it returns a string like this

```
NzI2NzU4NabNzEyMj24Ny1zYQ=
```

I'm given the assignment to create a url path as follows

```
DECLARE @url_path VARCHAR(4000) 
SET @url_path = 'https://www.website.com/payment?code=' 

DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR(4000) = ''
EXEC @ReturnValue = LWP_PAYMENT_URL  @order_no, @dept

SET @url_path = @url_path + @ReturnValue
SELECT @ReturnValue, @url_path
```

My goal is to take the hard coded `url_path` and get the encoded string from the execute and save it in a variable and concatenate it to the `url_path`.

What I'm seeing is that the string is returned part of the execute call instead of setting it to `@ReturnValue` and then looks like I get a zero value being saved and concatenated.

Added these are the final two lines of the `LWP_PAYMENT_URL` procedure.

```
DECLARE @Encoded VARCHAR(500) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), (SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, @string) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64))
SELECT  @Encoded AS [Encoded]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please define "returns a string." Does `LWP_PAYMENT_URL` have a `RETURN` statement (which can only return integers and which should be used only for error/status and not for data), or a `SELECT` (which you can't _assign_ values from and which should not be used to give back a single scalar value), or an `OUTPUT` parameter (which you should be using but haven't tried to use here)?

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker it has a final select statement.

Comment: You should be assigning that value to an output parameter and consuming it that way. In order for T-SQL to consume the value(s) in a `SELECT` by calling a stored procedure, it would have to insert them into a #temp table using `INSERT #t EXEC`.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker so the internal procedure has to be updated to OUTPUT my encoded variable.  On top of that I have to take that variable and put it into a temp table then move it out of a temp table? Now here is the fun part --  if I can't change the SELECT (final SELECT) in that query can i still make this work? I may not be able to change it because the procedure is used elsewhere

Comment: No, if you change it to use an OUTPUT parameter then no temp table is required.

Comment: A stored procedure doesn't *return* anything except for a single integer, typically used to indicate success or failure. It sounds like this should probably be a *function*, or instead should assign the "return" value to an *output parameter*

Comment: @Stu that was discussed as well - only issue is its built as part of a larger process used by others/other procedures and api's etc. which makes it very limiting for me as far as changes go

Comment: Well, only you can decide whether the logic inside this stored procedure is worth copying to another module that works correctly, or if these other parts of the code can be tested to ensure you can change _this_ procedure to be logically better, or if you should use the really gross method of inserting to a #temp table.

Comment: we ended up building the functions, and got permission and updated the procedures to use the functions instead of adding temp tables and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure should be doing this instead:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LWP_PAYMENT_URL
  ...@input parameters...,
  @encoded varchar(500) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ...
  SET @Encoded = CONVERT(varchar(500),
    (SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, @string) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64));
END
```

And then the caller says:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(500);
EXEC dbo.LWP_PAYMENT_URL @order_no, @dept, 
  @Encoded = @ReturnValue output;
```

If you can't change the stored procedure, create a separate one, or a table-valued UDF as suggested in the comments, or (assuming there are no other `SELECT`s in the procedure we can't see):

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(ReturnValue varchar(500));
INSERT #foo EXEC dbo.LWP_PAYMENT_URL ...;
DECLARE @ReturnValue varchar(500);
SELECT @ReturnValue = ReturnValue FROM #foo;
```

That's gross, though, and basically an abuse of how data sharing should work in SQL Server.

Ideally what you should do is, if the logic is the same for all uses, put that logic in some type of module that is much easier to reuse (e.g. a table-valued function). Then this existing stored procedure can maintain the current behavior (except it would call the function instead of performing the calculation locally), and you can create a different stored procedure (or just call the function directly, if this is all your code is doing), and the logic doesn't have to be duplicated, and you don't have to trample on their stored procedure.

Comment: There are no other selects, its a pretty straightforward small procedure. One does some encoding based on several pieces of logic and a concatenated string.  The second takes that encoded string and concatenates it to a URL path (which may change in time and should be kept separately here)  but beyond that since its used by API logic and other procedures I can't really make too many changes to the original encoded string procedure